# QML "TypeError: Type error" when sending new source data to Loader component

Tags: qt, qml, flux, qqmlcomponent

So .. First of all, I am using FLUX architecture.
I have this base scene where it loads another scenes. The loader is located in a loader storage. Let's say I clicked a button, I will send action to the scene store which gets the message and send it to the loader storage to load the new scene. But whenever I do this, I get the error, "TypeError: Type error", even though I am using the normal or correct data because I tested it with just embedding the loader to a scene without using storage.

**BaseScene.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect_baseLoader
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    anchors.top: rect_header.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: 0
    color: "red"

    BaseLoaderStorage {
        id: storage_scene
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    StoreAdapter {
        storage_baseloader: storage_baseloader
    }

}
```

**HomeScene.qml**

```
onClicked: {
     AppActions.navigateTo("SalesScene.qml");
}
```

**BaseLoaderStorage.qml**

```
AppListener {
    property BaseLoaderStorage storage

    Filter {
        type: ActionTypes.navigateTo
        onDispatched: {
            console.log("MESSAGE = " + message.source)
            storage.source = SCENE_LOC + qsTr(message.source)
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseLoaderStore.qml**

```
Item {
    property alias source: baseLoader.source
    id: storage_basesceneloader

    Loader {
        id: baseLoader
        focus: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        property bool valid: item !== null
        source: SCENE_LOC + "HomeScene.qml"
    }

    Connections {
        ignoreUnknownSignals: true
        target: baseLoader.valid ? baseLoader.item : null
    }
}
```

The question is why it is giving me the said error, "TypeError: Type error", when I am passing the correct data to the Loader's source? 
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't get this error if you pass _correct data_ to the Loader :-). But your example is incomplete as I see ... what is `SCENE_LOC `? Also `HomeScene` must be an `Item` descendant. What `onClicked` related to?

Comment: Actually, I tried passing hard coded data to the Loader. E.G "TestScene.qml". Without using the storage and store QMLs, the Loader is doing fine. But, once I  applied the flux architecture, it gives me the error. 

SCENE_LOC contains the base path or location of the other scene QMLs. EG: "qrc:/Content/Views/Scenes/TestScene.qml"

HomeScene is an Item.

I use a simple button to test the navigation of pages and just added an "onClicked" property to the button which go to the scene store to receive some data and pass it to the storage to implement it. And that's when the error happens. :(

Comment: Ok, so you should update your example to [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to answer such question without running the code

Comment: Have you solved this issue?